# PS5 controller doesn't charge

Tags: controllers, ps5

I have bought controller to use on PC. But when I connect it to USB to charge, orange light glows once and stops. If I connect it to Mac, it glows solid orange with white middle light. It should blink orange when charging, right? I tried multiple cables, laptop charger, computer USB port charging, phone charger - orange just blinks once. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Everything appears to be working normally.

According to [the official PS5 manual](https://manuals.playstation.net/document/pdf/CFI-1015A-1.0_1.pdf):

> #### Charge your controller
>
> With your PS5 console turned on or in rest mode, use a USB
> cable to connect your controller to the console. When your
> console is in rest mode, the light bar on your controller slowly
> blinks orange. **After charging is complete, the light bar turns
> off.**

Emphasis mine.

In other words, since the orange light blinks once and turns off, that means your controller is already fully charged.

As for the different behavior on Mac, unfortunately the official manual doesn't really provide a list of colors and blinking patterns, but according to [Appuals](https://appuals.com/ps5-dualsense-controller-lights-guide/#:%7E:text=DualSense%20is%20Connected%20to%20a%20PC):

> #### Orange with White Light
>
> This is the default color scheme that your DualSense controller will stay in while connected to a Mac, iPad, iPhone, or Android device.

Which means everything is working as intended.

Since you never mentioned actually *using* the DualSense, we can only assume that it is working properly, and that there is no problem with it at all.

Comment: well I used it for an hour or so - it shouldn't be fully charged

Comment: @RiDi, it seems the DualSense has a battery life time of about 10-12 hours. 1 hour of usage means the battery should be around 90%. I'm not sure about the DualSense, but some consumer electronics devices refuse to charge when above 80%, to avoid wearing down the battery too much. I'm not saying there's nothing wrong with your DualSense, but at this point, I can't really say there is.